# Actor matching query does not exist

Tags: django

i have a model called **Actor** in the app **Crew**
whenever i try to call the actor detail function from this address,

`{% url 'Crew:view_actor' mov.slug %}`
iam getting the above error,

this is the **models.py**

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
class Parent(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True,default=None)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=50,unique=True,default=name)
    designation=models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True)
    about=models.TextField(max_length=2000,blank=True,null=True)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class Actor(Parent):
    photo=models.ImageField(upload_to='crew/actor',blank=True,null=True)
```

this is **path**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from Crew import views
app_name='Crew'
urlpatterns=[
    path('view_actor/<slug:aslug>', views.view_actor, name='view_actor'),
]
```

this is **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from Crew.models import *
# Create your views here.
def view_actor(request,aslug):
    context=Actor.objects.get(slug=aslug)
    return render(request,'crew_detail.html',{'context':context})
```

this is the address bar when the error occured
**http://127.0.0.1:8000/crew/view_actor/the-godfather**

it worked when i tried this address manually
**http://127.0.0.1:8000/crew/view_actor/al-pacino**

how can i fix this error?, how can i make the actor slug appear on address bar instead of movie name?

Comment: `{% url 'Crew:view_actor' mov.slug %}` Seems like you are trying to use `mov.slug` as if it were an actor, which it is not.  You haven't shown us this full html template, so it's hard to suggest how to improve things...

Answer (score 0):

You are sending `mov.slug` in your template so it renders view_actor path, which, in browser, looks like `/view_actor/the-godfather`. I assume Parent model is the one with movies slug?
Create Actor model which will have Many-To-Many field to Movies and simply add slug to that Actor model. Then you can make Class based view for Actor model, and get context data there